# Cannot resize VirtualBox display

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I was using Ubuntu on VirtualBox, but I installed Xubuntu desktop and now display of vm is smaller than my monitor and I cannot resize it. [image]

How to extend it?

Answer (score 6):

I installed Guest additions, tried several other methods which I found online..But later only I found out that my problem was with the settings of maximum guest screen size.

Go to : File -> Preferences -> Display, and check whether maximum guest screen size is set to Hint. If not, this is the solution for your problem. First set it as Hint. Then, set width to 1920 and height to 1200

Click Ok

Now, start your VM and go to :

View -> Virtual screen1 -> Set the resolution to 1920 x 1200

Finally, enable auto-resize guest display option in the View tab itself by simply clicking on it.

Comment: "...and check whether maximum guest screen size is set to Hint. "? There is no "hint"

Comment: 8/15/2021 There is a "hint" but there is no View->Guest Display->Auto-resize. So this doesn't work for VirtualBox version 6.1.26 Win10 host/Linux guest.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure you have installed the Virtualbox guest extensions in your virtual machine. Then, it should resize by itself. You can go into fullscreen mode by inputting  + F . By default, Hostkey is the right ctrl key, so that would be right ctrl+F. Use the same combination to exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

This will be the answer of all your Display resolution scaled related problem with Virtualbox. Here i list all the possible steps you can follow that will help to resolve those resolution scaled problem(like zoom out display) and to switch full screen mode,scaled mode and adjusting window size.

1.At top of Virtualbox:

Go to File -> Preference -> Display and set the Maximum Guest Screen Size to Hint; Width:1920 ; Height:1200

2.Have some knowledge about the Host Key.In my case, Right Ctrl is my Host key.To know yours Virtualbox host Key:

Go to File -> Preference -> Input -> Virtual Machine. Here you can see your Host key combination.

3.(Optional)If you're using some debain distro in Virtualbox; type this command in the terminal of OS that you have installed in Virtualbox:

$sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)

4.At top of Virtualbox:

Go to File -> Preference -> View ... Here, you will know about different display mode.

Im my case-

FullScreen Mode-- Host + f

Scaled Mode-- Host + c

Adjust window size-- Host + a

Note-- In my case , Host is my Right ctrl keyword(Host key is defined as Right ctrl )

Now, you can type those keyword and switch between different display mode... Like if you type Right ctrl + c , Virtual Machine window will now switch to Scaled Mode

Note:Main Menu bar is Hidden in Scaled Mode.You can access it by pressing Right ctrl + Home

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown your virtual box and in a terminal shell type the following command

VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution 1366,768

the 1366,768 is just what i have set for my screen resolution on my laptop, change this to whatever your current resolution is on the machine your running. This should maximize all screens to full 100% on all guest os's

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that guest additions package has not been automatically installed for some reason.

The solution is as follows,
1. In VirtualBox menu, select "Devices" --> "Insert Guest Addition CD image". A CD icon will appear in the Desktop of Virtual Machine. 
2. Double click the CD icon, then select "Run Software" in the top right corner.

Done.

Comment: This generates an error "Unable to insert the virtual optical disk c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuiestAdditions.iso into the virtual machine XYZ" VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED -- so it is probably already mounted. But there is no way to determine one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

after installing virtualbox guest additions, included with your virtualbox, by choosing the menu option to Insert guest additions CD, and then double click on it once it appears on the desktop, to mount it.

Then using a terminal, cd to the guest additions folder, and run the VBoxLinux file using sudo. After that:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

if it asks you about keeping a file or installing the new one, press i to select the new one/package maintainer's version;

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

installing **virtualbox-guest-x11** package as shown, also resolves the issue where the shared folders are not visible.

And installing this package (and rebooting the virtual machine) also resolves the guest window not autoresizing when the vm window is resized.

This also resolves the issue where paste after reboot no longer works and sudo VBoxClient --clipboard command needs to be repeated. After installing  virtualbox-guest-x11, the --clipboard command does not need to be repeated after each reboot.

Comment: The installation of virtualbox-guest-x11 is clean, but this has no effect on the failure to maximize the window size to full screen.

Comment: However, it *did* finally work when I ran "sudo VBoxClient --clipboard" suggesting that if you follow every bit of advice in this thread (not just this answer, but the others too) some combination of them will work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may need some updates as time goes to year 2022. For Vbox 6.1, Ubuntu 20 LTS host and guest OS, most time the non-resize-able VM screen issue results from the so-called "Seamless Mode", which provides a miniature screen for ease-of-use by the administrators.

To avoid this issue, one can first change the "Maximum Guest Screen Size window" from "Automatic" to "Hint", then set "Width" and "Height" to the Maximum Screen sizes the host machine allows, such as 3840x2160 for 4K display. This change should be done when one is starting the VM.

After that, switch VM to use "scale mode". The switch option is available under "View" menu item of the VM when it is on the way of starting.

This should solve the screen resize issue for nowadays systems. Don't worry about the Guest Addition, it has been embodied into Virtualbox package already. Check "File"->"Preference"->"Extensions" and one can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your Guest Machine-General's Display “Scale Factor” and your

Guest-Settings's Display “Resolutions”.

When a new virtual machine witness on Mac/wins, the first step is to adjust virtual

machine's scale factor and maximum screen size, second step is to adjust

guest's scale factor, third step is to adjust guest's resolution, fourth

step is to restart host machine(e.g: macOS/Windows).

```
Please do the same functional operations on your Ubuntu, VirtualBox.:)
```

e.g:

My host machine `macOS` Retina display is `13.3 inch` (`2560×1600`);

My virtual machine VirtualBox`6.1.32` Max scale factor is `300%`;

And, VirtualBox default interface is `400×300`with scale factor `100%`;

Now,

1.VM scale factor and max screen size:

click `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

move your mouse to top menu, found out `VirtualBox`logo, select

"`Preference`", then enter "`VirtualBox – General`", click `Display`,

Choose "`Maximum screen size`" to "`Hint`" with Width "`1280`" and

Height "`800`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`", then click

"`OK`".

2. Guest scale factor:

When you enter `VirtualBox` APP, then you see "`Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager`",

found out your guest machine name button, as mine is "`linux_debian_11`",

you will see "`Power Off`" under the name of your guest machine.

Please found out your guest machine "`Menu Box Button`", that is at the right

of your guest machine name, right-click your "`Menu Box`" or single click your

"`Guest Machine Box`", choose "`Settings`", then you will enter your guest

machine's "`General`", mine is "`linux_debian_11 – General`", then click

"`Display`", and adjust "`Scale Factor`" to "`200%`"(the same as `Scale Factor`

on virtual machine's "`General`").

3. Guest Resolution:

My guest machine is "`Debian`". So, just use "`Debian`" for an example here.

Click my guest machine "`Debian`"'s “Settings”, then found out "`Display`",

and, also, choose "`Resolution`" to "`1280×800(16:10)`".

No matter your Debian version is "`8`", or even "`11`", the upstairs settings

Is OK.

Are you ok? Said, Lei Jun.

4. Reboot Host Machine:

Now, it's your time show!

Please restart my Mac.

Finally, "`Guest Resolution`" *  "`Scale Factor`" == "`Host Display size`".

"`1280×800`" * "`200%`" == "`2560×1600`";

VirtualBox Default interface is 400×300 with "`100%`", it's too small, so

"`Scale Factor`" should be from "`100%`" to VBox's max "`300%`". Also, has:

"`2560×1600`" * "`100%`" == "`2560×1600`"; (But VirtualBox Enter Wins will

too small just like VirtualBox default interface.)

"`1024×640`" * "`250%`" == "`2560×1600`"; (But guest machine "`Debian`"'s

resolution display do not have "`1024×640`".)

Answer (score -2):

you can resize it from corners of the window

Comment: No, I cannot do it.

Comment: you miss understood what "user" ask about